# Get reverse cumulative density function with NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, random, probability-density

I am interested in a particular density, and I need to sample it "regularly" in a way that represent its shape (not random).

Formally, `f` is my density function, `F` is the corresponding cumulative density function (`F' = f`), whose reverse function `rF = F^-1` does exist. I am interested in casting a regular sample from `[0, 1]` into my variable domain through `F^-1`. Something like:

```
import numpy as np
uniform_sample = np.linspace(0., 1., 256 + 2)[1:-1] # source sample
shaped_sample = rF(uniform_sample) # this is what I want to get
```

Is there a dedicated way to do this with `numpy`, or should I do this by hand? Here is the 'by hand' way for exponential law:

```
l = 5. # exponential parameter
# f = lambda x: l * np.exp(-l * x) # density function, not used
# F = lambda x: 1 - np.exp(-l * x) # cumulative density function, not used either
rF = lambda y: np.log(1. / (1. - y)) / l # reverse `F^-1` function
# What I need is:
shaped_sample = rF(uniform_sample)
```

I know that, in theory, `rF` is internally used for drawing random samples when `np.random.exponential` is called, for example (a uniform, random sample from `[0, 1]` is transformed by `rF` to get the actual result). So my guess is that `numpy.random` does know the `rF` function for each distribution it offers.

How do I access it? Does `numpy` provide functions like:

```
np.random.<any_numpy_distribution>.rF
```

or

```
np.random.get_reverse_F(<any_custom_density_function>)
```

.. or should I derive / approximate them myself?

Comment: in numpy you could only do this numericaly, so better do it by hand (ie explicitly use the inverse distribution `rF`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

scipy has probability distribution objects for all (I think) of the probability distributions in `numpy.random`.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html

The all have a `ppf()` method that does what you want.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.ppf.html

In your example:

```
import scipy.stats as st

l = 5. # exponential parameter
dist = st.expon(0., l) # distribution object provided by scipy
f  = dist.pdf # probability density function
F  = dist.cdf # cumulative density function
rF = dist.ppf # percent point function : reverse `F^-1` function
shaped_sample = rF(uniform_sample)
# and much more!
```

Comment: This looks great! I'll have a look :) ... awesome! It just works out of the box. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

As far as I'm aware there isn't a way to do this directly in numpy. For the case of functions where the cumulative distribution is analytic but its inverse isn't I generally use a spline to do the inversion numerically.

```
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline

x = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 1000)
F = cumulative_distn(x) #This we know and is analytic

rF = UnivariateSpline(F, x) #This will then be the inverse
```

Note that if you can do the inversion of `F` to `rF` by hand then you *should*. This method is only for the case where the inverse cannot be found in a closed form.

Comment: Fair enough ;) Does `numpy` provide at least the `cumulative_distn` (aka `F`) for each distribution it offers?

Comment: `numpy` doesn't but the distributions in [`scipy.stats`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/stats.html) generally provide the method `cdf` which will be the comulative distribution.

Comment: Great! Both `UnivariateSpline` and `cdf` will be very useful then. Cheers :)